# Why when I create an object with an array prototype I get an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I created the variable p with a prototype array

```
const p = Object.create([])
console.log(p)
```

I have got the next result in Firefox `Object {  }`, and chrome `Array {}`. When I use array methods they work as they should

```
p.push(1)
console.dir(p) //Object { 0: 1, length: 1 } OK
```

But when I use the assignment operator, I get the next result

```
p[1] = 2
console.dir(p) // Object { 0: 1, 1: 2, length: 1 } length !!!
```

Comment: Please specify your question.

Comment: Hey, as documentation suggests `Object.create` returns an `Object`. It will only look like an Array though, as you've passed its `prototype` to it - it'll have instance methods like any Array instance. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 2):

The Object.create() method creates a new object, using an existing object as the prototype of the newly created object.

So the result of Object.create([]) is an object. When you use "push" method for this object, actually it is found by following sequence:

1. find the method under p object, not found.
2. find the method under prototype reference of p, which is [], not found.
3. find the method under prototype reference of [], which is Array.prototype.push

So when push is execute, the length is changed to 1.
But if you assign value by yourself like

```
p[1] = 2
```

it is just a property under p object, length is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Array constructor to create an Array. Also bear in mind that Arrays are also objects.

Taking the example from mozilla:

```
let fruits = new Array('Apple', 'Banana');

console.log(fruits.length); // 2
console.log(fruits[0]);     // "Apple"
```

I would recommend you to read this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array

Good luck in your learnings :)